# How to access a RHDM 7.0 git repository in OCP environment?

Tags: drools-guvnor, jboss-tools, redhat-brms

Trying to access RHDM7 git repository hosted in an OCP environment.
This is what I have tryied so far:

1. Create a project in my OCP instance with :

   ```
   oc new-project demo-rhdm7-dtf
   oc create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gpe-mw-training/bxms_decision_mgmt_foundations_lab/master/resources/rhdm7-only.yaml
   oc new-app --name=dm-demo -n demo-rhdm7-dtf --template=rhdm7-only -p RHT_IMAGE_STREAM_NAMESPACE=openshift -p KIE_ADMIN_PWD=test1234! -p MAVEN_REPO_PASSWORD=test1234! -p APPLICATION_NAME=demo
   ```

   **Notes:**

   - rhdm7-only is a template created from github repository
   - the openshift namespace should include the imagestreams from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jboss-container-images/rhdm-7-openshift-image/rhdm70-dev/rhdm70-image-streams.yaml
   - The Deployment configs are paused by default, please take a moment to resume the rollout.
2. Create an space using Decision Central. In my case I am creating the `Acme` space.
3. In the created space create a new project, in my case `demoinsurance` project.
4. Do a `port-forward` for the nio git ssh port: 8001. I am following this tutorial example: http://www.schabell.org/2017/03/how-to-access-jboss-brms-internal-git-repo-in-container.html

   ```
   oc new-project demo-rhdm7-dtf
   oc port-forward $(oc get pod -l=deploymentconfig=gpte-rhdmcentr --template='{{ range .items }} {{ .metadata.name }} {{ end }}') 8001:8001
   ```
5. Try to use your favorite git client and clone:

When trying to clone as in the example (using git protocol through the ssh port) I get:

```
git clone git://127.0.0.1:8001/Acme-myrepo
...
fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: SSH-
```

When trying with ssh protocol:

```
git clone ssh://adminUser@127.0.0.1:8001/Acme-myrepo
...
ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to 127.0.0.1 port 8001: incorrect signature
```

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

When forwarding and using git port (9418)

```
git clone git://127.0.0.1:9418/Acme-myrepo
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
```

and the repository exists.

And by the way, by checking the pod's .niogit repository you can see Acme-myrepo.git repository:

```
$ oc rsh $(oc get pod -l=deploymentconfig=gpte-rhdmcentr --template='{{ range .items }} {{ .metadata.name }} {{ end }}')
$ ls $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/data/bpmsuite/.niogit
Acme-myrepo.git  datasets.git  datasources.git  myrepo.git  plugins.git  preferences.git  security.git  system.git  system_ou
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Close.
After further review:

https://github.com/jboss-container-images/rhdm-7-openshift-image/blob/rhdm70-dev/decisioncentral/image.yaml#L67

allows the use of the following environment variable in the template configuration:

JAVA_OPTS_APPEND = "-Dorg.uberfire.nio.git.ssh.algorithm=RSA"

which allows to use ssh protocol:
git clone ssh://@localhost:8001/

and the ssh protocol will request the password for the decision central user.

Note that there is a port-forward from OCP pod to localhost: oc port-forward $(oc get pod -l=deploymeconfig=gpte-rhdmcentr --template='{{ range .items }} {{ .metadata.name }} {{ end }}') 8001:8001

Comment: Hi Diego,
Is there a way to export a project created within Decision Manager 7 to Git or maybe download the project src to local? 
I don't see the src anywhere in the pod terminal either. Someone asked this a couple months back without any response: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50938708/2986579 
Could you help?

Comment: I have added instructions to the ones presented here:  stackoverflow.com/q/50938708/2986579