# How can I export & import a local project in Decision Manager?

Tags: rule-engine, redhat-brms

I'm using Red Hat Decision Manager,

I had my projects done and I wanted to deploy it to another pc.

All I can get is a jar file but when I import it Decision Manager responded Not project found.

Hoping for any help please.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

An additional way to export a project from Red Hat Decision Manager:

1. Login to Decision Central
2. Enter to the project that you want to export.
3. Click on any of the assets available in the library (this will take you to the project explorer view)
4. From the project explorer view, toggle the project navigation.

[image: project explorer navigation]

5. From the project navigation gears icon, select the `Download Project` option.

[image: settings gear]

Now you can unzip and use the project in any other git repository.

Comment: Thanks Diego, that's much easier. Is there a way to directly export the repo to Git and manage the code on the fly? With BRMS6.4 we could add a post-commit hook in `.niogit/repo-name.git` and that would automatically post changes to GIT. Is there a way to do that with DM7 running on Openshift?

Answer (score 0):

#### To Export

I found a way to do it, perhaps not the best approach but I couldn't find anything better.
Here is what I did:

1. Find out the mountPath of the pvol from your Decision Manager - Deployment Config.
   `/opt/eap/standalone/data/bpmsuite`, you can find the `.niogit` directory here.
2. Login to oc from your local and download the local repo from `.niogit`. You can use `oc rsync my-pod:/opt/eap/standalone/data/bpmsuite/.niogit/myrepo.git ~/temp/`. This will download the `myrepo.git` to a temp location on your machine.
3. Create a new Git repo.
4. From the temp `myrepo.git` directory on your local, add upstream origin to GIT: `git remote add origin git@github.com:my-demo/test.git`
5. Push the code: `git push -u origin master`

This is not straight-forward but this should do. If you, or anybody found a better way to do it, please let me know.

#### To Import

1. Login to your Decision Manager.
2. Click on `Design`
3. Click on `three-dots` on right-top corner, and select `Import Project`. Specify your GIT URL and authentication (if any).